# How to homogenize a general map?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading  *Algebraic Geometry, A Problem Solving Approach*, section 1.8.

(I put a picture of this page)

[image]

In the Exercise 1.7.3, we can give a map $\tilde{\psi}$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to the circle $V(x^2+y^2-1)\subset \mathbb{C}^2$, in fact, $\tilde{\psi}(\lambda)=\left(\frac{2\lambda}{\lambda^2+1}, \frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lambda^2+1}\right)$. I understand how this map is derived, and then it goes, ``to work in projective space, .... we have to homogenize our map''. I have no idea how to extend the map $\tilde{\psi}:\mathbb{C}\to V(x^2+y^2-1)\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ to

$$\psi:\mathbb{CP}^1\to \{(x:y:z)\in\mathbb{CP}^2: x^2+y^2-z^2=0\}$$

as $\psi(\lambda :\mu)=(2\lambda\mu:\lambda^2-\mu^2:\lambda^2+\mu^2)$.

I have already know that if $p(x,y)$ is a polynomial with highest sum degree $n$, then $z^np(x/z, y/z)$ will homogenize $p$. But could you help to give some explaination about how to homogenize a general rational map?  Or please give me some keywords to google.

Comment: If you want to homogenize a rational map, can't you just homogenize the numerator and denomiator to the lcm of their degrees? That should give you a homogenous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from
$$[\lambda:1]\to\left[\frac{2\lambda}{\lambda^2+1}: \frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lambda^2+1}:1\right]$$
Then replace $\lambda$ by $x/y$ to get

$$[x:y]=[x/y:1]\to\left[\frac{2x/y}{(x/y)^2+1}:\frac{(x/y)^2-1}{(x/y)^2+1}:1\right]=\left[2x/y:(x/y)^2-1:(x/y)^2+1\right]=\left[2xy, x^2-y^2:x^2+y^2\right]$$
If you are affraid by the poles and the zeros then $=$ is in the sense of rational maps.

Since always one of the terms is nonzero then
$$[x:y]\to \left[2xy: x^2-y^2:x^2+y^2\right]$$ is your globally defined morphism on the projective closures.

It is unclear if an arbitrary morphism of projective varieties will always be represented this way by a single homogeneous polynomial map not vanishing anywhere, that's why we deal with charts to define the morphism locally where it has to be given by some regular functions.